# Could I use baby jubjub curve to implement BulletProofs?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I use this [gnark-crypto baby jubjub](https://github.com/ConsenSys/gnark-crypto/blob/master/ecc/bn254/twistededwards/twistededwards.go) to implement BulletProofs, but it seems can not work well. But I use secp256k1 that will work well. So I'm wondering that if I can use baby jubjub curve to implement BulletProofs or should I do some modifications on the curve?

Comment: For those who, like me, do not know common pairing-based curves: the specification of Baby-Jubjub is [there](https://iden3-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/33717d75ab84e11313cc0d8a090b636f/Baby-Jubjub.pdf). It aims to be "a  specific  elliptic  curve  defined  over  the  large  prime  subgroup  of (the) BN128 elliptic curve". BN128 is "a Barreto-Naehrig curve, providing 128 bits of security", "over a 254 bit prime field".

Comment: So I wonder if baby jubjub can do the same operation as bn254? Such as Neg、ScalarMul、ScalarBaseMul、Add. When I try to use baby jubjub, I don't know what's it Infinity Point(O), such as using G as generator. r is the order, G^{r} = O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with that. It works right now. Because of `IsOnCurve`, I need to replace it with `IsInSubGroup`.